# How to marshal POJO to XML when rootelement is added to each XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

If i want to make a "product" via API POST method i need to send this XML payload inside body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<prestashop>
    <product>
        <active>1</active>
        <description>Some desc123TEST</description>
        <description_short>Short DESC EZ</description_short>
        <id_category_default>4</id_category_default>
        <id_shop_default>1</id_shop_default>
        <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
        <name>Product added by object HI</name>
        <price>44.12</price>
        <show_price>1</show_price>
        <state>1</state>
    </product>
</prestashop>
```

So as you can see my Product object is like wrapped with <*prestashop><*/prestashop> element.

I tried to model my Product to Java code and ended with this:

```
public class Product
{
    private int id_category_default;
    private int id_shop_default;
    private int show_price;
    private int state;
    private int minimal_quantity;
    private int active;
    private String description;
    private String description_short;
    private String name;
    private double price;


    public Product(...) {

    } ....
```

After marshaling this Product class to XML i got such XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<product>
    <active>1</active>
    <description>Some desc123TEST</description>
    <description_short>Short DESC EZ</description_short>
    <id_category_default>4</id_category_default>
    <id_shop_default>1</id_shop_default>
    <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
    <name>Product added by object HI123123</name>
    <price>44.12</price>
    <show_price>1</show_price>
    <state>1</state>
</product>
```

As you can see my marshaled Product object is not wrapped inside Prestashop element. Is there any way to add such element around Product XML?

Comment: How about a Pretashop object that contains one (or more?) Product objects?

Comment: I thought about it just not sure of its right. Cause prestashop object should then contain every other object like: address, image, quantity and many many MANY more. Maybe. Should give it a try...

Comment: What do you mean other object? There is just product object, so `public class Pretashop{}` can contain only Product

Comment: Maybe i missunderstood something. I meant that Product XML is wrapped inside <prestashop></prestashop>; user XML is wrapped inside <prestashop></prestashop>; so is product image XML, and any other object is wrapped inside <prestashop></prestashop>